# PHP error for files as "undefined index extension" pathinfo

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: extension
>
> Filename: vadmin/ajax.php
>
> Line Number: 88

Here is my code

```
$org_filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($org_filename);
        $file_extension = $path_parts['extension'];
        /***** end extracting file extension ******/
        
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/news';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 1000;       
        $final_file_name = $config['file_name'] = 'news_'.time().'.'.$file_extension;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pass `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` in [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$org_filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$file_extension = pathinfo($org_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

or `substr()` :-

```
$file_extension = substr($org_filename, strrpos($org_filename, '.')+1);
```